# Minecraft Server Pinger

Tags: python, windows, minecraft

In this python script I wanted to try and Ping my Minecraft Java Server so it could always stay online.  I'm not to familiar with servers, especially Minecraft Servers.  Does anyone know how to do this, or how to fix my Script.

```
import requests
import time

#Minecraft Server Pinger

server_ip="Server.aternos.me"

port={"Server.aternos.me": 12345678910}
#      Server IP             Port

while True:
    time.sleep(280)
    server_ping=requests.post(server_ip, port)
    print(server_ping)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package called [mcstatus](https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus) that does this easier if you don't want figure out how the networking for pinging works.

Just run `pip install mcstatus`

And then your code is as simple as:

```py
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer

server = MinecraftServer.lookup("example.org:1234")

latency = server.ping()
print(f"The server replied in {latency} ms")
```

Comment: There is some error:

```
import time
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer

print("Minecraft Server Pinger")
Server = input("Enter Your Minecraft Java Server IP (Example:  Server.aternos.me):  ")
Port = input("Enter Your Minecraft Java Port Or Host (Example: 12345678910):  ")
while True:
    time.sleep(280)
    server = MinecraftServer.lookup(Server,":",Port)
    latency = server.ping()
    print(f"The server replied in {latency} ms")
```

Comment: You copy/paste his code, not the error that you got @Viridian

Comment: Yes, but what is the issue with my code?

Comment: @Viridian It's hard to know the issue without knowing the error. The error tells you what the issue is.

Comment: It's okay I figured it out but thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Use mineflayer its availible for python with nodejs or for javascript.
Make a request to connect and intsantly disconnect from ur aternos server every 1 minute

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35686081)

Comment: I figured this out quite a while ago even so thank you for the answer though okay.